# Chrome is closing my ajax post at exactly 60 seconds

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-chrome, spdy, stalled

I am submitting some information that takes longer than 60 seconds to process, for some reason Chrome is closing that connection at exactly 1 minute. We also have the page cached with Akamai but they say that their timeout is 120 seconds, so something else must be causing the problem. We don't have timeouts in our angular code or anywhere close. Here is the output from Chrome's net internals. This only happens in Chrome, IE and Firefox process the submit fine.

```
t=191705 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=60081]
t=191705 [st=    0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=191705 [st=    0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=60080]
                       --> load_flags = 672000 (BYPASS_DATA_REDUCTION_PROXY | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                       --> method = "POST"
                       --> priority = "LOW"
                       --> upload_id = "0"
                       --> url = "https://qa2.web.com/payment/submit"
t=191705 [st=    0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=191706 [st=    1]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=191706 [st=    1]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=191706 [st=    1]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=191706 [st=    1]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 4578 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=191706 [st=    1]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=191706 [st=    1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=191706 [st=    1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_HTTP2_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                           --> :host: qa2.web.com
                               :method: POST
                               :path: /payment/submit
                               :scheme: https
                               :version: HTTP/1.1
                               accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
                               accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
                               accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
                               content-length: 317
                               content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
                               cookie: [2043 bytes were stripped]
                               origin: https://qa2.web.com
                               referer: https://qa2.web.com/payment/submit
                               user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
t=191706 [st=    1]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=191706 [st=    1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=60079]
t=191706 [st=    1]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                           --> delta = -317
                           --> stream_id = 313
                           --> window_size = 65219
t=251785 [st=60080]        HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR
                           --> description = "SPDY stream closed with status: 6"
                           --> status = -337
                           --> stream_id = 313
t=251785 [st=60080]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
                         --> net_error = -337 (ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=251785 [st=60080]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                       --> net_error = -337 (ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=251786 [st=60081]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=251786 [st=60081] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                     --> net_error = -337 (ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick workaround for **ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR**:

- Open a new tab in your Chrome browser
- As URL enter: **chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active**
- Click on the arrow in the right corner
- From the drop-down menu click on flush sockets
- Try the affected URL again

[image]

In your case, maybe it would be necessary to diagnose your application behavior in-depth and why this behavior triggers this issue.

Regards